# Discord.js, cannot read property "user" of null

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have a trouble, that I can't understand at all.
The function working on my server, and not working on another one.
Here's my code:

```
const user = message.author;
let servericon = message.guild.iconURL;
let serverembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setAuthor(message.author.username, auser.displayAvatarURL({ format: 'png' }))
.setTitle("Информация о сервере")
.setColor("RANDOM")
.setThumbnail(servericon)
.addField("Название сервера :", message.guild.name)
.addField("Владелец :", `${message.guild.owner.user.tag}`, true)
.addField("Каналы :", message.guild.channels.cache.size, true)
.addField("Роли :", message.guild.roles.cache.size, true)
.addField("Сервер создан :", `${moment(message.guild.createdAt).format('MMMM Do YYYY')}`)
.addField("Пользователей :", message.guild.memberCount)
.setThumbnail(message.guild.iconURL())
.setTimestamp()
message.channel.send(serverembed);
```

And error is:
(node:11288) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of null
at Object.run (C:\Users\alumetryu\Desktop\bot\commands\info\serverinfo.js:20:48)
at Client. (C:\Users\alumetryu\Desktop\bot\ame\index.js:38:17)
at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\alumetryu\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\alumetryu\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\alumetryu\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\alumetryu\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\alumetryu\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\alumetryu\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:125:16)
at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\alumetryu\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:797:20)
at Receiver.emit (events.js:315:20)
at Receiver.dataMessage (C:\Users\alumetryu\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:437:14)
at Receiver.getData (C:\Users\alumetryu\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:367:17)
at Receiver.startLoop (C:\Users\alumetryu\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:143:22)
at Receiver._write (C:\Users\alumetryu\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:78:10)
at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:403:12)
at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:387:5)
at Receiver.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:318:11)
at TLSSocket.socketOnData (C:\Users\alumetryu\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:872:35)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:295:12)
(node:11288) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:11288) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: Assuming the error is in the code you've shown, it would suggest that `message.guild.owner` is null, you could check if it's null, `addField("Владелец :", \`${(message.guild.owner ? message.guild.owner.user.tag : "-")}\`, true)`

Comment: Thank you to, shoejep, for helping me.
I have solved this!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the owner of the guild isn't cached. Instead, manually [`fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=fetch) the `GuildMember` with [`Guild.prototype.ownerID`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=ownerID)

```js
// make sure the function is async!
const owner = await message.guild.members.fetch(message.guild.ownerID);
const serverembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed().addField(
 'Владелец :',
 `${message.guild.owner.user.tag}`,
 true
);
```

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure exactly which line the problem is because the lines are not numbered in stackoverflow, but I'm assuming that the problem is in the line that says
`.addField("Владелец :", ${message.guild.owner.user.tag} , true)` - I'm guessing you're trying to get the owner, if so, here's how `message.guild.owner` - By the way, for anyone who doesn't know, guild is basically a server. So each guild, is each server the bot is on. message.guild, means the guild/server the message was sent from. Taking it even more deeper, message.guild.owner, is the guild/servers owner. If you have any questions feel free to reply to this post

Comment: @alumetryu good job! I see you're new to stack overflow, welcome to the community!